# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2022

I am running a python program on a server with windows server 2022

it always worked before, but since the last update I always get this error when trying to connect to a websocket:

[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)]

I already tried things like restarting and pip install --upgrade certifi

nothing worked so far.

it would be great if anyone can help

I already tried things like restarting and pip install --upgrade certifi

nothing worked so far.

it would be great if anyone can help

Comment: *"but since the last update"* - the last update of what? What might have been changed? If you refer to an update of the server  certificate the new one was likely configured wrong. But at the end are way too few information here to provide real help and not just speculations.

Comment: sorry, I mean the last "windows 2022 server" update